# Gradle jar including classes from dependency

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project having multiple modules say utils and core.
settings.gradle

```
include 'utils', 'core'
```

core/build.gradle

```
jar {
    destinationDir = file(LIB_DIR)
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.cohesity.spotlight.Main'
        )
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files("$buildDir/libs/utils.jar")
}
```

The core.jar is containing classes from utils.jar. Why is this happening?

Comment: _Might_ be because of the your `compile` dependency. If you need to depend on the utils subproject, use `compile project(':utils')`—see [Authoring Multi-Project Builds - Project lib dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

I think I know this one! (I've been baffled by it myself)

I'm guessing there are java source files packed inside `utils.jar`. By default `javac` will also compile these "implicit" sources alongside your sources from `src/main/java`. To stop this you'll want to pass `-implicit:none` to the compiler.

Eg:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
   options.compilerArgs << '-implicit:none' 
}
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html (search for "implicit")